Does Hope Everthorn's 'duplicate' ability also copy the tokens on the conjuration?
Hope's 'duplicate' ability says:

Choose a conjuration you control with a life value of 1. Place a copy of that conjuration onto your battlefield. At the end of this turn, destroy that copy.

Does this ability also copy the tokens (wound, exhaustion, status)?
The ability is similar to Strange Copy, which does not say that the tokens on the copied card are copied. So the tokens probably also aren't copied with the duplicate ability?
